# OOP reading a class of objects to a list from the database

Tags: c#, class, oop, methods

If I have a class defined as Person that outlines the fields of person and one of people that just contains a list of the person's like so:

```
 public class Person
{
public Person(){}
public int personID {get;set;}
public string name {get;set;}
public string address {get;set;}
}



public class People
{
   public People(){}

   public List<Person> peoples {get;set;}

  public List<Person> getPeople()
  {
    List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
    //create database connection
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()
    string SQLSelct = @"select * from people where active=1";
    //open datareader


    Person onePerson = new Person();
    //write data to each property type and add data to list

    p.Add(onePerson);
    return p;

   }

}
```

To call the database method that gets the people from the database.

```
    static void main(string[] args)
{
   People p = new People();
   p.getPeople();


}
```

Is this how I would do this in terms of OOP. 
I'm just beginning to use these techniques in my coding as usually I would do this to get the list:

Remove the getPeople() from the People class and do this in main:

```
        List<Person> people = getPeople();

 static void main(string[] args)
 {
   List<Person> people = getPeople();
 }


    private static List<Person> getPeople()
    {
        List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
        //create database connection
        //open datareader
        //load data into list

        Person onePerson = new Person();

        p.Add(onePerson);
        return p;

    }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Programmers.SE or CodeReview.SE

Comment: I guess my real question is when I am trying to retrieve data form a database in OOP do I perform this method in the class method like I showed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can remove the empty constructors, since they do nothing. Then, don't bother making a People class if it's just a list with a database read method. Your Person class is fine. I think, however, that you're starting at the wrong side.

You should start by deciding what your program does: Maybe you have an airport and you're handling schedules. In that case, begin with the Airport. Decide what it does. If parts are a logical group, such as a Schedule or a Plane, you have a good opportunity to make a class. Make sure to name your methods well; `getPeople` does not really tell the purpose. Consider `LoadPeopleFromDatabase`.

Ultimately, your goal should be to model your problem domain in ways that make it easy to separate logic from unrelated logic.